# Reading from file line by line and matching pattern - C

Tags: c, file, scanf, c-strings, fgets

I have a text file with lines like this:

> "string maybe contains more than one word - string as the previous -
> number"

I read from this file line by line with fgets, but the sscanf just cut off everything except the first string.
How can I solve this problem?

```
char new_name[30], new_district[30], buffer[100];
unsigned new_part_count;
while(fgets(buffer, 100, file)) {
    sscanf(buffer, "%s - %s - %u", new_name, new_district, &new_part_count);
}
```

Comment: Use scan-set in `sscanf()`, `"%[^-] - %[^-] - %u"`. Check if it returns `3` after successful parsing. Make sure `buffer` & other string variables have sufficient space for data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following call

```
sscanf( buffer, "%29[^-] - %29[^-] - %u", new_name, new_district, &new_part_count );
```

If to use just the conversion specifier `%s` then any white space character terminates the input of a string.

Comment: But you cannot have a space after the `[^-]`, since the character after the match is expected to be `-`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell No I can. It means that white spaces will be skipped before reading the next substring.

Comment: Ah, yes.  The space is reasonable for readability, but it will never actually consume any whitespace since all of that whitespace (what will fit!) will be consumed by the `[` specifier.

Comment: @WilliamPursell The white space after the symbol '-' and before the second substring allows to skip white space characters